# How to register a Spring 3.1 Printer or Parser in the FormatterRegistry

Tags: java, spring

Spring 3.0 introduced the [Type Conversion API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) and [Field Formatting API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format), containing
 [`Printer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Printer.html), [`Parser`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Parser.html), [`Formatter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html) (`Converter`), [`FormatterRegistry`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/FormatterRegistry.html)... (and Spring 3.1 introduced [`FormatterRegistrar`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/FormatterRegistrar.html).)

But I found no already build in way to register my own `Printer` or `Parser`. I only find a way to register `Formatter` in the `FormatterRegistry`.

So my question is, did I need to implement a way to register a `Printer` or `Parser` by my own, or did I have overlooked something.

*The question is NOT how to implement it by my own, the question is simple whether I have overlooked something.*

Answer (score 0):

Since a `Formatter` is **both**, a `Printer` **and** a `Parser`, you can implement this interface and register you class as described here: http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/